# Get dates for a given week number in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I would like to get dates for a given week number. For Instance, if I have the week number as 15, I need to get dates: **05-04-2015, 06-04-2015, 07-04-2015, 08-04-2015, 09-04-2015, 10-04-2015, 11-04-2015**.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Let me know,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 15);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);

    String result = "";

    int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    for (int i = firstDayOfWeek; i < firstDayOfWeek + 7; i++) {
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
        result += new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(c.getTime()) + "\n";
    }
```

As an input, except for the week, you need to have a year.
Pay attention that the first day of week depends on Locale.

Comment: Thanks. Gives out the required result!

Comment: Always gives the same value.

Comment: @TheDevMan so did you get the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
int yourYear = 1997;

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
c1.set(yourYear, 1, 1);
c1.add(Calendar.DATE, WEEK*7); 
for (int i = 0, i < 7; i++){
 String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
 System.out.println(formatted);
 c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
// set the date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 10 - 1, 12);

// "calculate" the start date of the week
Calendar first = (Calendar) cal.clone();
first.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 
          first.getFirstDayOfWeek() - first.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

// and add six days to the end date
Calendar last = (Calendar) first.clone();
last.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);

// print the result
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(df.format(first.getTime()) + " -> " + 
                   df.format(last.getTime()));
```

}